# How to add all files and directories to svn with the svn add command?

Tags: svn

I want to use this simple command, which is already recursive:

```
svn add *
```

The problem is that the shell (ash) does not expand the asterisk to hidden files, i.e. files whose name begin with a dot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, you just can to use:

```
svn add directory
```

Every file and subdirectory will be added correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, neither bash nor tcsh do that either. Simply use `svn add * .*` then.

Comment: `svn: Skipping argument: '.svn' ends in a reserved name`               `svn: warning: '.' is already under version control`  
`svn: Path '..' ends in '..', which is unsupported for this   operation`                                                            `# svn status
?       .test`

Comment: @dash17291: `svn add *` in a directory which already is a working copy usually results in SVN complaining about items already added. Same happens when you "manually" try to add the very same file a second time.

Answer (score -2):

svn add --depth infinity directory
Directory and all files will be included